# About harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

For harmonic functions $u,v$ from $D \subset \mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb R$ can we say the following: $ u + v $, $u^2$,$v^2$,$\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ are also harmonic under the same conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Why should that be true? Take $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$. It is an harmonic function, but $u^2$ is not.